# How to create my own log files on AWS Elastic Beanstalk using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, logging, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

It seems like AWS Elastic Beanstalk has no persistent local storage and I'm not able to create my application's own log files.
Has someone found a way to do it?

Thanks.